# How do I know if a remote machine is using Windows or Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, networking, protocol

Is there some way to run a command (such as ICMP message or another protocol), get a response from a remote machine (not on my own private local network) and analyze the message to find some evidence that this machine is running a Windows or a Linux operating system?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information? It may not be reliable...

Comment: Actually I was on a custumer last week and he was using a system that prevent anyone to use a Windows system on his network. It was made by a remote server that was not one the same network, I thout it very strange because I didn't know how it was made.

Comment: There are any number of ways you might do that.  For example, if you are using DHCP to provide network addresses, the DHCP request includes information about the client OS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It isn't definitive but [nmap](http://nmap.org/) will do this with the command `nmap -O -v` ([see docs](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html) for more details) If you're running windows or want a gui, look at [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/)

Comment: Mind you - some providers will detect port scanning using nmap as abuse.

Comment: @JeroenBaert namelly AWS sent me a scary email

Answer (score 11):

If you're on an IPv4 network, just use ping.  If the response has a TTL of 128, the target is probably running Windows.  If the TTL is 64, the target is probably running some variant of Unix.

Comment: What do you mean by propably?

Comment: What about TTL=255? I think is Unix..

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a TTL of 255.

Comment: What is the explanation for this/Why is this the case.

Comment: @Hervian, if you mean why were those particular TTLs chosen, you'd have to ask the original programmers.  If you mean why are most or all UNIX variants all the same and/or why the TTL is the same for every version of Windows, that would just be inertia - in the absence of any particular reason to change something, it tends to stay the same.

Comment: 255 is the direct gateway. 254 and below are more distant routers, each time one hop further away.

Comment: I also noticed that SANs are responding with a TTL of 254 or below...

Answer (score 2):

```
: Presumes ping service enabled on Windows local and remote hosts
:
del _IX.txt, Windows.txt
ping -n 1 [computername|ipaddress] | findstr /i /c:"Reply" > ttl.txt
for /f "tokens=1-9* delims=:=< " %%a in (ttl.txt) do (
    if %%i leq 130 (
       if %%i geq 100 (
          echo Windows & rem or echo %%c >> Windows.txt
       ) else (
          if %%i equ 64 (
             echo *IX & rem or echo %%c >> _IX.txt
          )
       )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can this modified to work with a range of IP's? If I wanted to run this to find all of the ttl's for my whole server stack.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to use [NMap](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html). From the response, it can guess the remote OS.

Answer (score 1):

Package: xprobe 'OR' xprobe2
Description: Remote OS identification
 Xprobe2 allows you to determine what operating system is running on a remote
 host. It sends several packets to a host and analyses the returned answers. 
 Xprobe2's functionality is comparable to the OS fingerprinting feature in nmap.

Example:
 $ sudo apt-get install xprobe
 $ sudo xprobe2 -T21-23,80,53,110 ###.###.###.###

Reference:
 http://www.sys-security.com/html/projects/X.html
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/xprobe/

Answer (score 0):

Old post but thought I would add to this too, if the device is SNMP enabled you can also query for the sysDescr which will tell you the OS it is using.

Download a MIB browser, a good one that I use is here: http://www.ireasoning.com/downloadmibbrowserfree.php. You basically give it the IP address of the device and do a walk operation.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to accomplish that?  Thanks.

Comment: You can download a MIB browser, a good one that I use is here http://www.ireasoning.com/downloadmibbrowserfree.php.  You basically give it the ip address of the device and do a walk operation

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of Johnathon64, you could use SNMP to query directly on the server 
- assuming the remote server itself is configured to use SNMP. You could launch a command-line query such as the one below to do it:

```
snmpget -v1 -c public <RemoteServerIP> sysDescr.0 | sed -n 's/.*STRING: //p' | tr -d \"
```

Explaining the command itself:

1. `snmpget` will query the object sysDescr, which contains the object's default name.
2. The following `sed` will exclude the beginning output, which only contains the polled OID and the beginning of the string.
3. The last command, `tr`, will exclude any double-quotes, usually found in the SNMP query.

The last two commands are only for formatting the output - if you don't need them, may use the very first command to extract the complete output.

Answer (score -1):

`cd` is a common command between Windows and Linux systems.

If you send something erroneous like `cd +`
The Linux systems I've tested will give you something like,

> -bash: cd: +: No such file or directory

Always starting with a shell ID, a reference to the problem character, and ending with "No such file or directory"

Windows always gives,

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Even simpler...

`cd` in Linux gives no output

`cd` in Windows gives the current directory as output

Programmatically you can identify the system based on the output of `0` or `>0` characters.

I created a switch using these patterns so that I could run a simple project on either Linux or Windows without modifying anything.

Comment: OP asked about *remote machine*, so obviously one can't run a local command