# Default Listening Ports in Linux

Tags: linux, port

Are there any default listening ports in Linux, like 135 and 445 for directory services in Windows?

While searching for a remote machine, I need to identify whether the machine I am connecting to is Linux or not, to perform some scripting operations based on OS.

I can't use tool like NMap, Since my application is a commercial one and Source code should be a closed one.

Comment: What are you [really trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here?

Comment: @BlacklightShining He's trying to identify a remote machine's operating system based on the ports it has open, I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: you won't be able to do this. nmap/zenmap probe the IP implementation itself to profile the OS. each TCP/IP stack implementation has idiosyncrasies in how they respond to different kinds of input packets (flags, syn/ack values, fragments, etc) and nmap has a database of indicators which can be used to try to determine teh os in question.

Comment: @BlacklightShining: Mr. Moses is right.

Comment: @FrankThomas: I know Mr. frank. But I can't use GPL Licensed tool for my commercial application. But I need to detect OS atleast approximately to reduce my runtime. That's why posted this question.

Comment: so open source advice to write closed source code? guess you'll have to do the same homework the nmap team did.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Yes. Have to do that. I know. Planning to do OS Finger Printing as NMap did :) but  for  the initial cut, I wanted to know is there any tricks to find it by ports?. But I guess it  is not possible. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has no default "signature" ports, since many of the ports that it uses are not unique to it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common listening port on linux systems is port 22 (used for `ssh`).

You can check for other open ports by calling `lsof -i` (as root) on the linux machine.

Also an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/394803/191912) to a similar question (which was solved by using `nmap`) suggests, that you could find out the operating system using only the `ping` command.